# Why do I Not see the background center my page

Tags: html, background-image

I have this html5

```
 <body>
         <!--[if lt IE 7]>
             <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please         <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

         <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
         <div id="content">
             aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        </div>

         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
         <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
         <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

and I have this css :

```
 /* ==========================================================================
    Author's custom styles
  ========================================================================== */

.content { 
    display:block;
    background:url (../img/boek.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
}
```

But I do not see the background at all and certainly not centered on the page.

Roelof

Comment: Is the path correct? is anything in the path missspelled?

Comment: You select in CSS with the `.` (class) selector, but you've made `content` the ID in html. Use the `#` selector instead, for starters, i.e. `#content { ...}`.

Comment: thanks, the text is now centered but still no image. Can it be the problem that I have already made a background-image on the html tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. Use the `#` selector instead of `.` (class), because you've set it as an `id` in the html.
2. Get rid of the space between `url` and the argument.

This should work:

```
.content {
     background-image: url('../img/boek.jpg');
}
```

Have a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/NuUHR/) for an example.

---

If you haven't already, invest some time in learning how to use a developer toolbar (Chrome Dev Toolbar, Firebug, etc). It can be a tremendous help in finding the cause of CSS problems quickly, and allows you to easily spot if the image from the URL you specified is loading correctly at all.